# Using a variable in xpathSApply

Tags: r, xpath, xpathsapply

Consider the following example of **web scraping** using **R**.

```
m <- "https://stackoverflow.com"
doc <- htmlParse(GET(m))

hello <- length(xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href[contains(.,'stackoverflow')]"))
hello
[1] 48
```

The XPath function I use gives me the number of all links that contain the string `"stackoverflow"`.

My goal is to replace the string `"stackoverflow"` in the XPath function with a variable. Like this:

```
my_variable <- "stackoverflow"
hello <- length(xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href[contains(.,my_variable)]"))
```

It doesn't work for now cause the data variable is considered a string. Can you please help me to explicit `my_variable` is a variable?

Comment: Use `paste` for the xpath: `paste0("//a/@href[contains(.,'", my_variable,"')]")`

Comment: Works like a charm! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer has been given by Parfait : Use paste for the xpath:

```
paste0("//a/@href[contains(.,'", my_variable,"')]")
```